How to Reinitialize JavaScript Functionality for Dynamically Added Elements Without Duplicate Event Listeners?
I am developing a social media platform using Django for the backend and a purchased HTML template from ThemeForest for the frontend. The template was built using React and then exported to plain HTML, CSS, and a large JavaScript file (over 26,000 lines). I am encountering issues when trying to dynamically add new elements to the DOM and reinitialize the JavaScript functionality for these new elements.
Issue:
The large JavaScript file contains all the necessary functionality to handle UI interactions, animations, and event listeners. Initially, when the page loads, everything works fine. However, when I dynamically add new posts (e.g., when the user scrolls to the bottom of the page to load more posts), the new elements do not have the JavaScript functionality applied to them.
To address this, I wrapped the entire code from the large JavaScript file into a function called reinitialize. After adding new elements, I call this reinitialize function to apply the necessary JavaScript functionality to the new elements. This works, but it introduces a significant issue: duplicate event listeners are added to existing elements, causing unexpected behavior (e.g., click events firing multiple times).
Scenario:
Initial Page Load:
On initial page load, the template's JavaScript file initializes all elements correctly.
<div id="posts-container">
    <div class="post">
        <!-- Post content here -->
        <button class="like-button">Like</button>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="/static/js/large-file.js"></script>
<script>
    // Initial call to reinitialize all elements
    reinitialize();
</script>

Adding New Posts Dynamically:
When the user scrolls to the bottom, new posts are fetched and added to the DOM.
function loadMorePosts() {
    fetch('/load-more-posts')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            data.posts.forEach(post => {
                let postElement = document.createElement('div');
                postElement.className = 'post';
                postElement.innerHTML = `
                    <!-- Post content here -->
                    <button class="like-button">Like</button>
                `;
                document.getElementById('posts-container').appendChild(postElement);
            });

            // Call reinitialize to apply JavaScript functionality to new elements
            reinitialize();
        });
}

// Event listener for scrolling to the bottom
window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
    if (window.innerHeight + window.scrollY >= document.body.offsetHeight) {
        loadMorePosts();
    }
});

Problem:
Each time reinitialize is called, it adds duplicate event listeners to existing elements, leading to issues such as event-listeners cancelling each-other out which won't make the button click, but I react to a post which will call the reinitialize() function again to format the reactions correctly, the button click will work because there will be three eventlistener attached to it, two cancel eachother out and the third one take over (like not really cancel, like toggle).
Question:
How can I reinitialize the JavaScript functionality for dynamically added elements without causing duplicate event listeners and other conflicts? Is there a more efficient way to handle this scenario?
Attempts and Considerations:

MutationObserver: I considered using MutationObserver to detect new elements, but I still need to reapply the functionality without causing duplicates.
Selective Reinitialization: Ideally, I would like to reinitialize only the newly added elements, but the current structure of the large JavaScript file makes this challenging.

Example Code:
Here is the code snippet illustrating the problem:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Social Media Platform</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="posts-container">
        <div class="post">
            <!-- Post content here -->
            <button class="like-button">Like</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <script src="/static/js/large-file.js"></script>
    <script>
        // Initial reinitialization
        reinitialize();

        function loadMorePosts() {
            fetch('/load-more-posts')
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(data => {
                    data.posts.forEach(post => {
                        let postElement = document.createElement('div');
                        postElement.className = 'post';
                        postElement.innerHTML = `
                            <!-- Post content here -->
                            <button class="like-button">Like</button>
                        `;
                        document.getElementById('posts-container').appendChild(postElement);
                    });

                    // Call reinitialize to apply JavaScript functionality to new elements
                    reinitialize();
                });
        }

        window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
            if (window.innerHeight + window.scrollY >= document.body.offsetHeight) {
                loadMorePosts();
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>

Any advice or solutions to efficiently reapply the JavaScript functionality to newly added elements without causing duplicates would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
This is the complicated javascript here: app.min.js

Really you should just work with the original React code instead. You cannot solve this without modifying the "complicated javascript".

@Bergi actually I don't have access to the React code

That's a shame. I hope you didn't pay too much for that template…

OMG! Is it not possible? I'll try to reach out to the person, but I would really appreciate it if there is another solution to resolve this. Perhaps we can work on an open-source project that can remove all event listeners from all elements and then reload a full JavaScript code, like React for vanilla JavaScript-based projects.

There might be ways, just not very efficient ones… and of course you can always reverse-engineer the javascript file they gave you. But really the proper way to do it is to make use of react for this, if you already have it, and to work with the original source code for that.
